# How to save a json file in documents directory?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I want to save my json file in document directory and read it from document directory in iOS. I've seen only tutorial for string or image, but if I want to save a json I don't know how.

Comment: JSON, is just `Data` or `String`. So there is nothing different from there...

Comment: You added your JSON file in Xcode and want to store that file in the document directory right?

Comment: It so simple. You can just create a .text file in directory and paste whole JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to create JSON data is to use a JSONEncoder:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

let data = try encoder.encode(yourJsonObject)
```

That gives you a `Data` object in the variable `data`. As others have said, saving a `Data` object to documents is quite easy. The code would look something like this (the below is intended as a guide and may contain minor  syntax errors.)

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}

func saveDataToDocuments(_ data: Data, jsonFilename: String = "myJson.JSON") {

    let jsonFileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(jsonFilename)
    do {
        try data.write(to: jsonFileURL)
    } catch {
        print("Error = \(error.description)")
    }
}
```

To read an object from a JSON file in your documents directory:

- Build A URL to the file using the `getDocumentsDirectory()` function above, along with `URL.appendingPathComponent()`
- Use the Data method `init(contentsOf:options:)` to create a Data object from the file's contents.
- Create a `JSONDecoder` and use it to convert your data to a JSON object. (Your object will need to conform to the Codable protocol.)

Comment: Thank you so much, and how i can get json from document direcotry?

Comment: Just reverse the process. Read the data from your documents directory, and then use a JSONDecoder to convert it back to an object.

Comment: Can you make an example of code ? I'm very grateful